# Setting a timer in python for cookie expiration

Tags: python, cookies

I want to alert the user when the session is about to expire (with a pop-up window, or otherwise, in js).

In my settings I have:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 3600
```

I'm trying to get the cookie expire time with:

```
expires = cookie.expires
exp_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(expires)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But right now I'm getting:

```
2017-11-14 10:38:50
```

Which doesn't make sense.

How can I get the remaining time of a cookie?

Comment: Are you using a web framework like django or flask or anything?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your fromtimestamp with an int value is going to work correctly. I think its best to rely on djangos built in methods. What you can do is use the get_expiry_date() on your session. So in a view do something like this

```
def index(request):
    print(request.session.get_expiry_date())
    return render(request, template_name='index.html')
```

and the output i got was

`2016-11-16 17:49:05.062808+00:00`

and when i check the type it was a datetime

`datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 16, 17, 51, 41, 887459, tzinfo=<UTC>)`